# What function does the tmp keyword serve in this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been asked to go through a former coworker's code, and for the life of me, I can't figure this query out. It's extracted from PHP, hence the way variables and quotes are used, but it's the query that I'm trying to figure out.

```
"UPDATE item SET shipment_id = '' WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM item WHERE purchase = ".$purchase." AND repair_status <> 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, ".$count.") tmp ) AND purchase = ".$purchase." AND repair_status <> 4"
```

Separating everything out with a bit of psuedocode for clarity, I get this:

```
UPDATE item SET shipment_id = '' WHERE id IN ( subquery1 ) AND purchase = ".$purchase." AND repair_status <> 4;

subquery1:
SELECT id FROM (subquery2) tmp

subquery2:
SELECT id FROM item WHERE purchase = ".$purchase." AND repair_status <> 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, ".$count."
```

The one I've dubbed "subquery1" is what I don't understand. We don't have any tables or fields named 'tmp', and I've gone over the mysql reserved words - it's not there either. He's no longer around to ask him, so that's not an option. What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: It's an alias for the subquery. It's required by the MySQl syntax, even though it might not actually be used. Think of it as `SELECT someColumn FROM someTable AS tmp`

Comment: I believe it you two are right. I always thought 'as' was a required part of using an alias, so that never occurred to me.